How to connect to LDAPS with Symfony 6.4 Framework and self signed certificate?
I have a Symfony 6.4 WebApp with a working Service to connect to LDAP. Of course I use the LDAP-Component of Symfony. This is working, but if I want to use LDAPS it does not. With an old Web App, without using Symfony I put the following line before LDAPS-Connection and it works fine:
putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');

With Symfony, this isn't working.
Symfony is installed on Ubuntu which is running Apache Web Server.
Here is my code so far:
.env.local:
LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never
LDAP_CONNECTION_STRING=ldaps://192.168.15.201:636
LDAP_IP=192.168.15.201
LDAP_USERNAME=company\Administrator
LDAP_PASSWORD=strong_secret
LDAP_DOMAIN=company.local
LDAP_ENCRYPTION=tls
LDAP_VERSION=3

LdapService.php:
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Exception\LdapException;

class LdapService
{
    private $ldap;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {

            
            putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');

            
            $connectToLdap = $_ENV['LDAP_CONNECTION_STRING'];
            $ldapUsername = $_ENV['LDAP_USERNAME'];
            $ldapPassword = $_ENV['LDAP_PASSWORD'];

            
            $this->ldap = Ldap::create('ext_ldap', ['connection_string' => $connectToLdap]);

            
            $this->ldap->bind($ldapUsername, $ldapPassword);
        } catch (LdapException $e) {
            echo 'LDAP Connection Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    public function getLdap(): Ldap
    {
        return $this->ldap;
    }
}

services.yaml:
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            $ldapService: '@App\Service\LdapService'
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    
    # Explicitly configure the LdapService
    App\Service\LdapService:
        public: true

ExampleController.php:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\LdapService;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Exception\LdapException;

#[Route('/ldapuser', name: 'app_ldapuser.')]
class LdapUserController extends AbstractController
{

    private $ldapService;

    public function __construct(LdapService $ldapService)
    {
        $this->ldapService = $ldapService;
    }
}

